# Operand should contain 1 column(s) MYSQL to create columns

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm new to SQL and my thought is to attempt this question:

1. creating a column for bonus_factor using CASE ( to cater more criteria to handle if there are)
2. would like to multiply the salary with bonus_factor to derive a bonus

   `SELECT employee_id,(salary*(SELECT*, CASE WHEN employee_id%2!=0 AND name NOT LIKE 'M%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS bonus_factor FROM Employees))AS bonus FROM Employees`

However, it throws me an error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

Tried to specify the column 'bonus_factor' in the subquery but it does not work as well.

Can someone help me to understand how can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your business logic? Are you trying to calculate the bonus by multiplying salary either by 2 or 0 based on the condition you defined?

Comment: `SELECT employee_id,salary*(CASE WHEN employee_id%2!=0 AND name NOT LIKE 'M%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) as bonus FROM Employees`

Comment: Hi @Cositanto thanks for sharing this, i understand this one, but i'm trying to figure out if there's any way to work on this if it's given more criteria

Comment: Hi @Extreme_Tough, yes i would like to 'create' another column called 'bonus_factor' and then multiplying the salary with the factors (2 or 0) . In the current Question from Leetcode it has 2 conditions (factor 2 or 0), im wondering if there's any workaround if there are more conditions and we can summarize the bonus_factor in a column before multiplying.

Comment: @user12101812 Your last comment doesn't make sense to me can you clarify with an example please.

Comment: @P.Salmon, for an example for condition A will have bonus_factor of 3, condition B will have bonus_factor of 2, condition C will have bonus_factor of 1 and condition D with bonus_factor 0. Under this example, i would like to create a column of bonus_factor and call out the bonus column in the SELECT statement using 'Salary' * 'bonus_factor'

Comment: Hello guys, i think I have got this..but not sure it makes sense

SELECT employee_id,CASE
                    WHEN employee_id%2!=0 AND name NOT LIKE 'M%' THEN 2
                    ELSE 0
                   END AS bonus_factor,
                    (salary*(SELECT bonus_factor))AS bonus
FROM Employees

many thanks!